# Buttons not changing

Tags: java

```
 long totalMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSeconds = totalMilliSeconds / 1000;
    long currentSecond = totalSeconds % 60;
    long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
    long currentMinute = totalMinutes % 60;
    long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
    long currentHour = totalHours % 24;
    System.out.println("Current time is:" + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);


    if(currentHour <= 9 && currentHour >=18)
        readFile.setForeground(YELLOW);
        readFile.setBackground(BLACK);
        graph.setForeground(YELLOW);
        graph.setBackground(BLACK);
        search.setForeground(YELLOW);
        search.setBackground(BLACK);
        snippet.setForeground(YELLOW);
        snippet.setBackground(BLACK);
        prediction.setForeground(YELLOW);
        prediction.setBackground(BLACK);
        export.setForeground(YELLOW);
        export.setBackground(BLACK);
        back.setForeground(YELLOW);
        back.setBackground(BLACK);
```

The program is supposed to change the colours of buttons from 6pm up until 9am but im not sure why its still changing before the set time. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what is the output of your System.out.println() instruction?

Comment: Please check your if-condition: The value has to be less than or equal to 9 and at the same time greater than or equal to 18. Please also use curly braces for the body of the if-statement.

Comment: That was just to test that it was getting the right time JB Nizet

Comment: `currentHour` will NEVER be both smaller than 9 AND larger than 18

Comment: Yeah sorry I get what your saying now Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems with your code:

- The if-condition will never evaluate to `true`. For this, the value has to be less than or equal to 9 and at the same time greater than or equal to 18.
- Missing curly braces for the whole (containing *all* the color changing statements) body of the if-statement lead to

  ```
  if(currentHour <= 9 && currentHour >=18) {
    readFile.setForeground(YELLOW);
  }
  readFile.setBackground(BLACK);
  graph.setForeground(YELLOW);
  graph.setBackground(BLACK);
  ```

So a lot of the colors are set independent of your if-condition.

Comment: If you downvote, please add an explanation why.